# How to order properties with Json.NET, if a class has JsonExtensionData?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

### Current state

For an example class:

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public JObject First { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string Second { get; set; }
}
```

Properties from `JsonExtensionData` (property `First`) get appended to the serialized object after `Second` is there. For example resulting with:

```
{
    "second": "blah blah",
    "first": {
        "name": "value"
    }
}
```

### Desired state

```
{
    "first": {
        "name": "value"
    },
    "second": "blah blah"
}
```

It seems that `[JsonProperty(Order = x)]` does not apply to a property marked with `JsonExtensionData`. Any idea for how to achieve the desired state?

Comment: Hi, when you convert the object into a json object you should add additional parameter, check at this:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm

Comment: Your observation seems to be correct.  [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L491) serializes the extension data after the properties.  [`JsonExtensionDataAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm) doesn't even have an `Order` property.  Thus ordering the extension data seems not to be implemented.

Comment: In fact I'm sort of surprised the contract resolver doesn't throw attempting to make a a contract for your `Example` type as `[JsonExtensionData]` and `[JsonProperty]` conflict.  (Instead it simply assumes the former supersedes the latter.)

Comment: In order to get what you want you're probably going to need a custom contract resolver + custom converter combination.  Is it worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it can help you but you can try. By without mark `Order`, the defaut order -2 is assigned and it force appear first when serializable.

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public JObject First { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string Second { get; set; }
}
```