Map fields dynamically in c#.Need an alternative to Reflection
I have below fields in my class
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-1")]
 public string? LTRAMT1 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-2")]
 public string? LTRAMT2 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-3")]
 public string? LTRAMT3 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-4")]
 public string? LTRAMT4 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-5")]
 public string? LTRAMT5 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-6")]
 public string? LTRAMT6 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-7")]
 public string? LTRAMT7 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-8")]
 public string? LTRAMT8 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-9")]
 public string? LTRAMT9 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-10")]
 public string? LTRAMT10 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-11")]
 public string? LTRAMT11 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-12")]
 public string? LTRAMT12 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-13")]
 public string? LTRAMT13 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-14")]
 public string? LTRAMT14 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-15")]
 public string? LTRAMT15 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-16")]
 public string? LTRAMT16 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-17")]
 public string? LTRAMT17 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-18")]
 public string? LTRAMT18 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-19")]
 public string? LTRAMT19 { get; set; }
 [JsonProperty("LTR-AMT-20")]
 public string? LTRAMT20 { get; set; }
//using dictionary
//public Dictionary<string, string> LTRAMT { get; set; }

i dont get these fields in order in request body.based on position i have to map it respective LTRAMT fields
i have below method to do that
 public static string LtrAmounts(List<Amounts> amounts, int i)
 {
     var filter = amounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.position == i);
     return filter != null ? filter.value.ToString() : "";
 }

Request Body:
"amounts": [
                    {
                        "value": 0,
                        "position": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 1624.96,
                        "position": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 9901010,
                        "position": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 35776,
                        "position": 20
                    }
                ]

I tried using reflection it is working fine but response time is more.
 for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
 {
     ltr.GetType().GetProperty($"LTRAMT{i}").SetValue(ltr, amounts != null ? LtrAmounts(amounts, i) : "");
 }

Also tried dictionary
  private static Dictionary<string, string> AssignKeyAndValues(List<Amounts> amounts)
  {
      Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

     for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
     {
          string key = "LTRAMT" + i;
          string value = LtrAmounts(amounts, i);
          keyValuePairs[key] = value;
      }

      return keyValuePairs;
  }

But in the response i am getting parent object under that i have fields which is not my requirement
{
"LTRAMT":
{
"LTRAMT1":"0",
"LTRAMT2":"1624.96",
"LTRAMT3:"",
"LTRAMT4":"9901010"
.........
"LTRAMT20":"35776"

}
}

I don't want to sent parent LTRAMT in response.
Need help to complete this requirement.Any other suggestion will also be helpful
Thanks in Advance.

If u have a JSON, u can do a deserialization into a dynamic variable and access the properties without using any class, something like this:   dynamic? data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

How about having the underlying storage locally being an array, so setting by position is easy; and then the properties (LTRAMT1 etc) have custom getter/setter that uses the array?

Also, for return you may want to have a custom type converter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0

Can you share how you return the response? I believe that you are setting the LTRAMT as the parent field mentioned, it won't appear without a reason.

@YongShun when i use dictionary LTRAMT is added by default
//public Dictionary<string, string> LTRAMT { get; set; }

@D A i cannot because amounts i have to map based on position that are there in request body

I see, after you bind the data to dictionary, you assign the value to the LTRAMT property in a class instance. Actually when you try to return the response, you can just return the dictionary value, you don't need the class that hold the LTRAMT property.

If you only use the dictionary for the response (not the class with the LTRAMTx-Fields), you will get the desired result

@PinBack I have other fields too not only amounts sorry for not mentioning

If you use Newtonsoft, you can use the JsonExtensionData attribute.
See: JsonExtensionDataAttribute
The JsonExtensionDataAttribute instructs the JsonSerializer to deserialize properties with no matching field or property on the type into the specified collection. During serialization the values in this collection are written back to the instance's JSON object.
For example:
public class Tram
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> LTRAMT { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("OTHER")]
    public string Other { get; set; }
}

Note: You must use a Dictionary<string, object> not Dictionary<string, string>

I am creating that dictionary LTRAMT how can i make it Dictionary<string,object>
private static Dictionary<string, string> AssignKeyAndValues(List amounts)
{
Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
 {
      string key = "LTRAMT" + i;
      string value = LtrAmounts(amounts, i);
      keyValuePairs[key] = value;
  }

  return keyValuePairs;

}

Simply change the declaration: private static Dictionary<string, object> AssignKeyAndValues(List<Amounts> amounts) { Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>(); ...}

the solution worked but in the response it is not in the same order i map
For example:
Other fields
........
LTR-AMT-1
LTR-AMT-2
.....
LTR-AMT-20
Other fields
I need it in this way.But i see
Other fields
Other fields
LTR-AMT-1
LTR-AMT-2
......
LTRAMT-20

you need a special order for serialization? I think that is not possible with JsonExtensionData: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495387/how-to-order-properties-with-json-net-if-a-class-has-jsonextensiondata
